# How to avoid this type of change of digits in computed numbers?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, digits, output-formatting

Is there a way to avoid the digits being changed?

```
In[117]:= v=124.58061;
v1=v-0.00024;
v2=v+0.00024;
In[120]:= FullForm[v]
FullForm[v1]
FullForm[v2]
Out[120]//FullForm= 124.58061`
Out[121]//FullForm= 124.58036999999999`
Out[122]//FullForm= 124.58085`
In[123]:= FullForm[Interval[{v1,v2}]]
Out[123]//FullForm= Interval[List[124.58036999999997`,124.58085000000001`]]
```

I just want `124.58037` and `124.58085` in these outputs. For some other values of `v`, the Out[122] would also get a small bit change.

How could I avoid the changes? Eventually I want to save these numbers (which is part of a larger structured expression) into files, what's the right way to do it without causing additional changes to the numbers?

Comment: `124.58036999999999` is **exactly the same** as `124.58037` - there is no change in the number.  Evaluate `SameQ[124.58036999999999, 124.58037]` to see.  If you are trying to write this number to a file and want it written in a certain way, then the question should clarify that.

Comment: Do you realize that the actual numbers are stored as [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) reals?  The change, if you want to call it that, occurs when *M* displays the numbers as the closest 6-digit approximation.  What you see in the Front End is not the actual number.

Comment: If it is `SameQ`, why not using the more intuitive form for both display and writing?

Comment: @qazwsx Because Mathematica is not consistent with how it displays numbers to the right of the decimal point. There are plans to make it more consistent in version 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

There are two distinct issues at work:

1. Why is the result of the simple arithmetic operation different from what you'd expect?
2. How can we change the *display* (as opposed to the *value*) of a decimal number?

### How "Real" numbers are represented internally

The answer to the first question is simple: Some numbers cannot be exactly represented in binary (base 2) with a finite number of digits, just as $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{3}$ cannot be expressed in decimal (base 10) with a finite number of digits. Mathematica represents [`Real`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html) numbers internally as a single binary number called a floating point number, or float for short. On most systems, a 64-bit float only holds 53 binary digits for the mantissa (think scientific notation). You can see this for your numbers using [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html):

```
RealDigits[124.58061, 2, 54]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
> 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
> 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, Indeterminate}, 7}
> ```

That last `Indeterminate` is telling us there are no more known digits, and the 7 says how many digits are to the right of the decimal point (binary point?), a number Mathematica calls [`Accuracy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html). The bottom line is, converting from a finite number of decimal digits (what you entered) to a finite number of binary digits (internal representation) and then back again (for display) is not guaranteed to preserve the original input. This is fundamentally unavoidable when using floats.

### How "Real" numbers are displayed

But with 53 binary digits at our disposal, you have ~14 decimal digits to the right of the decimal point to work with, which is more than enough for your desired 5 sig figs. Now your problem is how Mathematica is choosing to display the numbers to you. Mathematica is not consistent here. None of your three numbers has a terminating binary representation, but that's not apparent from the output of `FullForm`.

## The Solution

### Change the display

Since you have plenty of digits of precision to work with, it seems to me you want to change the display of decimal numbers. You can do this with [`DecimalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DecimalForm.html). Here is the wrong way to use `DecimalForm`:

```
In[1]:= v = DecimalForm[124.58061, 9]
In[2]:= v1=v-0.00024
```

> ```
> Out[1]//DecimalForm = 124.58061
> Out[2]= -0.00024+124.58061
> ```

The number `-0.00024` is displayed to 2 sig figs, just as it was entered, while `v` continues to be displayed with 9 sig figs. Here's the right way:

```
In[3]:= DecimalForm[v=124.58061 , 9]
        DecimalForm[v1=v-0.00024, 9]
```

> ```
> Out[3]//DecimalForm= 124.58061
> Out[4]//DecimalForm= 124.58037
> ```

Notice the placement of the `=` (assignment) operator. Keep in mind this only changes the display of the numbers, not the internal representation.

### Change the internal representation

Alternatively, you can avoid using Mathematica `Real` numbers altogether. The best way is to use rationals instead as [Bill suggests in his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188130/27662).

```
In[5]:= v=Rationalize[124.58061,0]
        v1=v-Rationalize[0.00024,0]
        v2=v+Rationalize[0.00024,0]
```

> ```
> Out[5]= 12458061/100000
> Out[6]= 12458037/100000
> Out[7]= 2491617/20000
> ```

In each case, Mathematica has just reduced the fraction $\displaystyle \frac{x\cdot 10^5}{10^5}$. The `N` function will then give you as many decimal digits of precision as you'd like:

```
In[8]:= N[v2, 20]
```

> ```
> Out[8]= 124.58085000000000000
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
v=Rationalize[124.58061,0];
v1=v-Rationalize[0.00024,0];
v2=v+Rationalize[0.00024,0];
FullForm[v+0.]
FullForm[v1+0.]
FullForm[v2+0.]
```

which shows me 124.58061, 124.58037 and 124.58085.

But expecting floating point binary math to provide exact decimal results may be an ongoing source of frustration and problems.